# CSS: Why transform: scale is not working with justify-content: space-around?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm making CSS-only carousel and trying to give effect like below.

1) Active element has large scale/opacity value.
2) As far from active element, scale/opacity become small.

```css
.carousel {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel__box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 500px;
  background: skyblue;
}

.carousel__box:nth-child(1),
.carousel__box:nth-child(5) {
  opacity: 0.6;
  transform: scale(0.8);
}


.carousel__box:nth-child(2),
.carousel__box:nth-child(4) {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.carousel__box:nth-child(3) {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel__box"></div>
  <div class="carousel__box"></div>
  <div class="carousel__box"></div>
  <div class="carousel__box"></div>
  <div class="carousel__box"></div>
</div>
```

However, space between elements are not equal as I expected. How can I fix this? When I looked for SO question, it works with `transform-origin`. But, I couldn't find how solve this.

Comment: scale is only a visual effect and will affect the layout so your element are scaled after the space is defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaled (using `transform: scale`) element acts something like `absolute`, it doesn't affect other DOM element with it's size changes. Use `width` and `height` instead.

```css
.carousel {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel__box {
  --w: 100px;
  --h: 100px;
  width: var(--w);
  height: var(--h);
  background: skyblue;
}

.carousel__box:nth-child(1),
.carousel__box:nth-child(5) {
  opacity: 0.6;
  width: calc(var(--w) / 1.2);
  height: calc(var(--h) / 1.2);
}


.carousel__box:nth-child(2),
.carousel__box:nth-child(4) {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.carousel__box:nth-child(3) {
  width: calc(var(--w) * 1.2);
  height: calc(var(--h) * 1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel__box"></div>
  <div class="carousel__box"></div>
  <div class="carousel__box"></div>
  <div class="carousel__box"></div>
  <div class="carousel__box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I used width/height as variable!

Answer (score 0):

Consider margin to rectify the scale effect:

```css
.carousel {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel__box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 500px;
  background: skyblue;
}

.carousel__box:nth-child(1),
.carousel__box:nth-child(5) {
  opacity: 0.6;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  margin:0 -15px; /* you scale by 0.8 so -0.2x150px = -30px that we split on both side */
}


.carousel__box:nth-child(2),
.carousel__box:nth-child(4) {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.carousel__box:nth-child(3) {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  margin:0 15px; /* you scale by 1.2 so 0.2x150px = 30px that we split on both side */
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel__box"></div>
  <div class="carousel__box"></div>
  <div class="carousel__box"></div>
  <div class="carousel__box"></div>
  <div class="carousel__box"></div>
</div>
```

With CSS variable you can have something generic and easy to handle:

```css
.carousel {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel__box {
  --w:150px; /* the width */
  --s:1;     /* the scale factor */
  width: var(--w);
  height: 500px;
  background: skyblue;
  transform:scale(var(--s));
  margin: 0 calc(var(--w)*(var(--s) - 1)/2)
}

.carousel__box:nth-child(1),
.carousel__box:nth-child(5) {
  opacity: 0.6;
  --s: 0.8;
}


.carousel__box:nth-child(2),
.carousel__box:nth-child(4) {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.carousel__box:nth-child(3) {
  --s: 1.2;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel__box"></div>
  <div class="carousel__box"></div>
  <div class="carousel__box"></div>
  <div class="carousel__box"></div>
  <div class="carousel__box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I prefer width/height, anyway thanks!